# How to detect locale?

Tags: ios, swift, locale

I want to detect region and if it is not Spain I need to create check like this:

```
if myRegion == Spain {

    //some code

} else {

    //some code

}
```

I trying to do this like this but it is doesn't work:

```
let myRegion = Locale.current

if myRegion == Locale(identifier: "sp") {
    //some code
} else {
    //some code
}
```

**Update**

```
if myRegion == Locale(identifier: "es") {
    print("YES")
} else {
    print("NO")
} 

let locale = Locale.current
print(locale.regionCode)
```

It is doesn't work. In console I see:

```
NO
Optional("ES")
```

If I change es to ES it is is doesn't work.

Comment: The language code of Spain is `es` not `sp`.

Comment: what is your keyboard language ...or in setting u set somewhere another language this is problems because of that....

Comment: https://www.andiamo.co.uk/resources/iso-language-codes/ Spanish = "es".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 let myRegion = Locale.current.regionCode
 if myRegion == "ES" {
        //some code 
    } else {
        //s
    }
```

Spain region code is "es".You can find the list of codes here : [LINK](https://wpastra.com/docs/complete-list-wordpress-locale-codes/)

If you are in same country, the easiest way to find out the region code is:

```
let locale = Locale.current
print(locale.regionCode)
```

Comment: @user and also you need to declare `let myRegion = Locale.current.regionCode` not `let myRegion = Locale.current`

Comment: Done. But I have error `Cannot assign value of type 'Locale' to type 'String?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Locale.current.regionCode`.